# Can't sort by rails index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

I used the rails globalize and I18n gem. But now I can't sort my model. Can you guys help?

I tried adding a new index, but I'm not entirely familiar with indexing.

Controller.rb

```
def index
  @foods = Food.all.order(:name)

  add_breadcrumb "index", foods_path
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "food_translations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "food_id",    null: false
t.string   "locale",     null: false
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string   "name"
t.string   "bio"
end

add_index "food_translations", ["food_id"], name: "index_food_translations_on_food_id", using: :btree
add_index "food_translations", ["locale"], name: "index_food_translations_on_locale", using: :btree
add_index "food_translations", ["name"], name: "index_food_translations_on_name", using: :btree

create_table "foods", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "address"
t.string   "phone"
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.string   "yelp"
t.string   "youtube"
end
```

Comment: `name` is a property of `FoodTranslation`, not of `Food`. You are not showing any relationships there, but you need to include the `food_translations` table somehow in order to be able to sort on `food_translations.name`.

Comment: I see. I tried to join (FoodTranslations.name), but the syntax is definitely wrong.

Comment: The point is, you should include your model classes in your question, together with the relevant associations (such as `belongs_to`).

Comment: Does that mean I have to create a new model.rb? Food Translations was made by the gem.

Comment: There has to be some code somewhere that maps the food translations table into ruby objects. You could also include the name of the gem that you used, in case someone (not me) is familiar with it and what exactly it does. But I can tell you that you want to be doing a join, and the most natural way to do a join in ActiveRecord is by using associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need a join. If you do not have a model for the translation, you could just use .joins for your finder. Like:

```
   Food.joins('INNER JOIN food_translations ON foods.id=food_translations.food_id')
       .order('food_translations.name').where('food_translations.locale=xxx')
```

ps: I wonder why you do not have a index on "food_id" AND "locale" which should be uniq. In your case you can have two or more translations for 1 food in the same language.

Comment: food_translations.locale=xxx ? What do I put for locale? params[:locale]?

Comment: yes if that is set. I don't know how you have internationalized your app.

Comment: so should be like .where(['food_translations.locale=?', params[:locale])

Comment: One more thing, do you know why on my homepage

.where(['food_translations.locale=NULL)?

Comment: Good, yes you need to set a default.